# sql join with default parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, filtering

Assume I have a table called t_employee which has a name column and a company_id column.
I have a stored procedure where I can list all employees or just for a company,

```
create procedure p_listEmployees( @companyID integer = null)
```

In the procedure, rather than saying if @companyID is null .....
I would rather have the join deal with the fact that I may or may not be filtering.
I am sure some time ago I have seen this done using COALESC.

any thoughts?

Comment: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
from t_employee e left join company c on COALESCE(c.company_id,1) = COALESCE(e.company_id,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from t_employee e left join company c on c.company_id = e.company_id
where (@companyId is not null and e.company_id = @companyId)
or @companyId is null
```

Note that it's a left join.